# Difference between Deflater and GZip compression

Tags: java, compression

I am currently using `java.util.zip.Deflater` to compress. Also `java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream` can be used for compression. Here I focus on basically byte array compression.
Can any one let me know the difference between these Deflater and GZIPOutputStream. (performancewise..).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Deflater` produces zlib-wrapped deflate compressed data, unless `nowrap` is true, in which case it produces raw (unwrapped) deflate compressed data.

`GZIPOutputStream` produces gzip-wrapped deflate data.

deflate is a compressed data format defined in [RFC 1951](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1951).

zlib is a two-byte header and four-byte trailer that provides compact identification of the stream and integrity checking on the uncompressed data.  zlib is described in [RFC 1950](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1950).

gzip is a 10+ byte header and 8-byte trailer that provides metadata and integrity checking, where the metadata can include a file name, modification date, originating operating system, comment, and extra data.  gzip is described in [RFC 1952](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1952).

There is no difference with respect to performance, other than a few bytes difference in the header and trailer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference in performance as `GZIPOutputStream` only has one speed/compression ratio setting that is not changeable, while `Deflater` has ten possible ratios, from fastest+least compressed to slowest+most compressed. Here is a good article with graphs [about it](http://java-performance.info/performance-general-compression/).

Comment: @MarkAdler - Java impl of GZip does NOT allow to DIRECTLY change compression level setting, see its constructors and methods: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html. Internally it has access to "def" field which is of Deflator type which is the internal compressor for the stream. So one can override the stream to get access to the protected "def" and set level there but not directly via GZip.. interface.

Comment: Wayback machine link for article with graphs: https://web.archive.org/web/20171220132048/https://java-performance.info/performance-general-compression/